# Make node finish when done processing, even if the event loop isn't empty?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, event-loop

I'm making a local simulator for AWS Lambda, where [`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) can be set - this allows one to run a lambda without [disconnecting from database](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs). This is used to keep Lambda connections open on MongoDB, RethinkDB, etc.

> I'd like to emphasise that **I'm aware the normal, non-Lambda thing to do here would be to disconnect the database**. However the lower latency using `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` makes it preferable for Lambdas as it allows the microvm to remain connected to the database and for subsequent lambdas to reuse the same connection.

I'd like to simulate AWS's behavior locally.

**How can I create the equivalent of `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` = false (ie, exit as soon as all processing is done, rather than waiting for the event loop to be empty?**

Here is some demo code. Change `FUNCTION_NAME` to `'connectOnly'` or `'connectAndDisconnect'` to demonstrate the behavior.

Right now `'connectAndDisconnect'` works, but `'connectOnly'` does not - it finishes processing, but won't ever exit node since the connection is still open.

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var log = console.log.bind(console)
let minify = script=> '"' + script.replace(/\n/g, '').trim() + '"'

var functions = {
    connectAndDisconnect: `const rethinkdb = require('rethinkdb');    
    ;(async function(request, context) { 
        var connection = await rethinkdb.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }); 
        await connection.close();
        console.log('I connected successfully!');
    })();`,
    connectOnly: `const rethinkdb = require('rethinkdb');    
    ;(async function(request, context) { 
        var connection = await rethinkdb.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }); 
        console.log('I connected successfully!');
    })();`
}

const FUNCTION_NAME = 'connectOnly'

log(`Testing ${FUNCTION_NAME}`)

var functionToTest = functions[FUNCTION_NAME]

var child = spawn('node', ['-e', minify(functionToTest)], { 
    shell: true,
    stdio: [0, 'pipe', 'pipe'],
    cwd: 'C:\\Users\\mikem\\OneDrive\\Documents\\appless\\documentdb-arc-test\\src\\http\\get-index',
    env: {}
})

var completed = false;

let timeout = 5000;
// bake a timeout
setTimeout(function () {
    log(`Timed out after ${timeout} ms!`)
    child.kill()
}, timeout)

// 'close' will occur if the process finishes naturally
// 'exit' will occur if the process is killed
console.log(`What we want is to be see a 'close' event using the 'connectOnly' code above`)
;['close', 'exit'].forEach(function(event){
    child.on(event, function () {
        log(`'${event}' event happened!`)
        if ( ! completed ) {
            completed = true
            log(`Done!`)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve precisely? Also a minimal working example that requires no external components would be useful.

Comment: Does [lambda-local](https://github.com/ashiina/lambda-local) not work for you?  If not, you might take a look to see how they implemented it.  Of course, in the real Lambda environment, Node itself does not actually stop.  It remains running with the global scope intact, regardless of the setting.  The difference is only whether the response is returned immediately.

Comment: @mewa Precisely I am making an AWS simulator as mentioned. The minimal working example is provided above, an external component is used as I need something that starts a socket. You can swap RethinkDB for MongoDB and the same behavior will occur if you connect but do not disconnect.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's an excellent suggestion, I'll do that and report back,